# Compare columns of 2 different Data frames

Tags: python, pandas, ipython

I have 2 data frames df1 and df2, which have same column names but could have different order,

I am validating if these 2 dataframes are identical or not.

I want to compare these dataframes based on the column names.

```
df1:
A   B   C ...
1   1   1
1   2   4
5   3   8

df2:
A   C   B ....  
1   1   1
1   4   2
5   8   3
```

I want to compare df1.A & df2.A and so on .

would really appreciate if I could get help regarding the same ,

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, sort both dataframe columns lexicographically,

```
df1 = df1.reindex_axis(sorted(df.columns), axis=1)
df2 = df2.reindex_axis(sorted(df.columns), axis=1)
```

then compare.

```
df1 == df2
```

You don't need iteration. (Which means way faster)

Answer (score 0):

if you don't care about the columns being in order and are just concerned with seeing if they are all contained within each dataframe:

`set(df1.columns) == set(df2.columns)`